# How to download Firebase results as set?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, ios10

I have the following wrapped in a completion block:

```
dbRef.child("Employees").queryOrdered(byChild: "deptid").queryEqual(toValue: "100").observe(.childAdded, with: {
  snapshot in
  //add each result to an array
```

The problem is that the completion fires for each result. I need it to fire after all results have downloaded, which means blocking. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to :-

```
dbRef.child("Employees").queryOrdered(byChild: "deptid").queryEqual(toValue: "100").observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with:{ snapshot in
   if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

        for each in snapDict{

              let deptID = each.value["deptid"] as! String

        }
   }
})
```

Comment: Isn't this the same?

Comment: Nope, `childAdded` to `value`

Comment: I don't think so. Same.

Comment: You were using `.childAdded` as *FIRDataEventType*, i am using `.value` as *FIRDataEventType* , in what ways is it SAME???.. Give it a shot maybe?..

Comment: ah - sorry. Remaining text got clipped and made it look the same until you scrolled.

Comment: This is crashing the app. How do I pull out "deptId" now?  This no longer works:
           ` if let result = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let sdeptId = result["deptId"]! as! String`